# Are there any open source, hardware-accelerated crossplatform physics libraries with C++ bindings?

Tags: c++, physics, hardware-acceleration

I'm working on a game using OpenGL and C++. I would really like hardware accelerated physics, but cross-platform. Is there anything out there, maybe implemented in OpenCL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Bullet](http://bulletphysics.org) physics library is an excellent choice. It's a C++ library, with comprehensive  OpenGL demos, and supports OpenCL acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

[Open Dynamics Engine](http://www.ode.org/) is likely the most widely used one, but there are many others.